# software to track file (releases) sent to customers

Tags: software-development, file-management

I'm looking for something similar to a document management system, but not quite a DMS.
I get software packages, test them and then I send them out again. Sometimes there are also patches in between etc.
I'm looking for a software with which I can keep track of

- the date when I received the software
- the date when I recieved a patch (to a certain version number)
- the date when I sent out the
  (tested) software

In an optimal world I would this would be represented on a timeline or calendar.

Good would also be the possibility to tag the software packages and to ad certain "required fields" like a custom version information etc.

The files are quite big (ranging from a 80MB to 900MB) and are stored on a flat file system (remote storage). So it would be good if the software could access this (it's a nas so various means of access are possible).

I looked at redmine with DMFS-Plugin, but it does not realy meeet my requirements.

OS should be preferably Linux. Free would be nice, but there is also a budget if the software truly fits.

I'm grateful for any hints, even if it just checks some requirements!